# Changing hostname raises sudo resolving host error

Tags: sudo, hostname

Amongst other things, I am trying to change my hostname with a script. Basically the script `sed`s the values of `ubuntu` from `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.

I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04.4 in the past and worked well.

Now, on 16.04.6 (or just by chance), I am getting errors with the same script. Just as I change the `hostname`, the change on the `hosts` files takes a long time (probably because `sudo` is trying to reach the new host which has not yet placed in the `hosts` file but I did not know `sudo` uses such information) and I get an error:

`sudo: unable to resolve host xxxx`

Sometimes also `sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu`. Following script commands have the same problems or fail.

But obviously it is not possible to change at once the values of both files

**Why did this happen?** Is it something new in that Linux distribution version? I read other people having the same problem but never happened to me before, I was always able to edit both files with sudo with no other inconveniences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` uses glibc's libnss to determine hostnames. Usually (with 16.04) `nscd` is running. You may be racing against its cache expiration. Relevant config in `/etc/nscd.conf`:

```
    enable-cache            hosts           yes
    positive-time-to-live   hosts           3600
    negative-time-to-live   hosts           20
    check-files             hosts           yes
    persistent              hosts           yes
```

`check-files` will caused `nscd` to "periodically check...the modification time of.../etc/hosts."

I am ignoring complications introduced by nonstandard configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

You should have both the old and new hostnames in `/etc/hosts` until the old is no longer cached. Stopping `ncsd` and if `persistent` is `yes` then deleting `/var/cache/nscd/hosts`, and then starting `nscd` should work.

`/etc/hostname` is only consulted during boot and is irrelevant in this case.

Incidentally you should also set the hostname with `hostnamectl` and/or `hostname` which informs the kernel and any services that ask the kernel for the hostname e.g., via the `uname` system call, of the new hostname. `hostnamectl` does all sorts of other hostname settings as well because systemd.

Comment: Yes, I actually updated the `sed` with `hostnamectl` trying to fix the issue. The strange thing is that this never happened before.... will take your recommendation and update `/etc/hosts` before

Answer (score 0):

From sudoers(5) man page:

> A user specification determines which commands a user may run (and as
>   what user) on **specified hosts**.  By default, commands are run as root,
>   but this can be changed on a per-command basis.

Sudo configuration file (/etc/sudoers) allows to specify what command(s) an user can run, as another user(s) and on which machine(s). It is usefull if you have a lot of machines, as you can deploy the same sudoers file on different machines. Probably you have a line specifying the hostname as ubuntu (the former hostname). Run the `visudo` command, identify the line and edit it with the new hostname.

Comment: Mmm.. there is no line with any hostname in the sudoers file.

Comment: Can you post your sudoers file (you can remove the coments with the comand `sudo egrep -v '^\s*#|^$' /etc/sudoers`). Also, check for files in /etc/sudoers.d directory (files in this directory are an extension of sudoers file).

Comment: It is the standard Ubuntu file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059813/etc-sudoers-file-ignored-or-overrriden-somehow  (like in the question, except the pkaramol stuff)